# Calculations to forecast repayments on loans

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, finance

I'm working on a dataset which includes the salaries of recent graduates in various job sectors. The data consists of students that have graduated in 2020 throughout the UK. I have calculated tuition fees by multiplying it by the number of years it takes to complete the degree. Taking into account the difference in tuition fees for Scotland residences, and elsewhere but also that a medicine degree is longer than a bachelor of arts in history.

The aim is to forecast based on the initial salary for each sector, how long it would take for a person with a degree from a sector to pay off their loan.

My question is to understand the type of calculations or models that are most effective for my situation. I'm currently leaning towards the future value formula taking into account the interest rate of the student loan. However, I'd like to know if any others exist that perhaps take into account compensation, and promotions as 10 year work you're likely to have an increase in salary. Any help on this would be much appreciated!

I have read into the following: [predicting student loan debt](https://scholarship.rice.edu/bitstream/handle/1911/111013/StudentLoanDebt-AHierarchicalTimeSeriesAnalysis-GeorgeElsesser.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) 
which uses a hierarchical time-series model to make predictions on several variables. One of the variables used are 'repayment', given that I actually have data in the following structure:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 7
  salary degree     compensation region  tuition_fee interest_rate years_of_study
   <dbl> <chr>                <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>
1  29000 engineer              3000 england        9250          5.25              4
2  29000 mathematician         2000 england        9250          5.25              3
3  27000 biologist             1000 england        9250          5.25              3
4  28000 pharmacist            1500 england        9250          5.25              5
5  26500 films                 1500 england        9250          5.25              3
6  26500 historian             2000 england        9250          5.25              3
7  28000 business              1500 england        9250          5.25              3
8  29000 economics             2000 england        9250          5.25              3
```

Would I be able to implement a model similar to the article above with this data? The aim is to forecast the years it will take to repay the loan given its tuition fee amount, which we multiply by the number of years of study. Taking the interest rate into account, starting salary and yearly compensation.

The repayment is calculated by the following:

- £524 a week or £2,274 a month (before tax and other deductions)
  For example:

> You’re paid weekly and your income changes each week. This week your income was £600, which is over the Plan 2 weekly threshold of £524.Your income was £76 over the threshold (£600 minus £524). You will pay back £6 (9% of £76) this week.

Meaning 9% of the money above the threshold of £524 a week or £2,274 a month.

example code:

```
tibble(salary = c(25000, 25000, 27000, 25000, 23000, 27000, 28000, 29000), degree = c('engineer', 'mathematician', 'biologist', 'pharmacist', 'films', 'historian', 'business', 'economics'), compensation = c(3000, 2000, 1000, 1500, 1500, 2000, 1500, 2000), region = c("england","england","england","england","england","england","england","england"), tuition_fee = c( 9250, 9250, 9250, 9250, 9250, 9250, 9250, 9250), interest_rate = c(5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25), years_of_study = c(4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3))
```